# Printing address of a C array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

The below question may sound repetitive to the community but sometimes you need to ask the exact question in your mind to understand things correctly. I am trying to get a thorough understanding of pointers. I was watching a video when the presenter says print the address of each element of array by using &pointername[subscript]. My question is why not just pointer. In the below code after doing j++ wont J have address of the array elements? why should I use &j[k]? what is the difference between &j[k],j(if there is)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int i[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, *j, k;
    j = i;
    for (k = 0; k < 5; k++)
    {
        printf("%p, %p, %p\n", &j[k], j, i);
        j++;
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Sahana

Comment: You shouldn't in fact. If you increment `j`, it will point to consecutive elements. Maybe it should be `&i[k]` instead?

Comment: Don't printf pointers with %u :(

Comment: It's `int main(void)`; C is not Java. And pointers **must** be printed with %p and the corresponding argument cast to `(void*)`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant : I intended to print the address of every element in the array. The only way as far as i know is by incrementing j pointer.

Comment: @sahana no, it's not. `&array[index]` works just fine.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant,I agree with you. &array[index] is perfect. But if I want to use pointers then? In the above example which is correct:  &j[k] or j, which is the correct way?

Comment: @sahana `&array[index]` **is** a pointer. `j` is also a pointer. What's the problem?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Just trying different ways. I got different address when I printed &j[k] and j. I was curios. with my understanding both must print the same address in the above example.

Comment: @sahana Why should they? `j` is points to the element that… well, that `j` currently points to. `&j[k]` points to the element offset by `k`. Unless `k` is 0, they are not the same thing.

Comment: Your names are confusing. Traditionally (since Fortran77, and linear algebra books) `i`, `j` and `k` are often integers. Use some slightly better names like `arr` (for some array), `ptr` (for some pointer), `ix` (for some index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases when you refer to an array in C, what you automatically get is a pointer to the array's first element.  In other words, when you wrote

```
j = i;
```

it was *exactly* as if you had written

```
j = &i[0];
```

And this further means that when you write

```
i[k]
```

it is exactly equivalent to

```
*(i + k)
```

This then means that

```
&i[k]
```

will always be equal to

```
i + k            /* or &i[0] + k */
```

And in your program it's also true that `j[k]` is equal to `*(j + k)`, meaning that `&j[k]` is equal to `j + k`.

It looks like your program is trying to demonstrate these equivalences, but it's confusing because you're both incrementing `j` *and* indexing `j` by `k`.  Here's a version of your program that should make it more clear what's going on.  (Among other things, I've changed the array's name to `a`, because "i" is a *very* confusing name for an array!  Similarly, I've changed `j` to `p`.)

```
int main()
{
int a[] = {11, 22, 33, 44, 55}, *p, k;
printf("a = %p\n", a);
p = a;
for(k=0; k<5; k++)
    {
    printf("%d %p %p %d %d\n", k, &a[k], p, a[k], *p);
    p++;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's undefined behavior unless you cast the %p args to ptr-to-void.

Answer (score 3):

You are partially right:

- With the assignment `j=i`, `j` points to the first element in the array `i`. From now on `j[k]` will point to the same memory location as `i[k]`.
- With `j[k]` you are retrieving the data of the `k`-th cell in the array. So `j[k]` is an int.
- If you want to get the address of it you have to place a `&` in front of it.

Comment: "j is an array (so a pointer)" — so a pointer *what*? Do you mean that `i` is a pointer? Because it isn't. Also `j` isn't an array, it's a pointer.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant It's similar, but ok you are right, I remove it.

Comment: you can always write it *correctly:* `i` is an array, so it's almost always implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: Your first point is incorrect.   `j` is a pointer, not an array.  `i` is an array, and the assignment `j = i` is equivalent to `j = &i[0]`.  That does not make `j` become an array.   It just means that `j[k]` and `i[k]` refer to the same element.

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed that, I thought that j was the array.

Answer (score 1):

In C,  `&ptr[index]` is *exactly* the same as `ptr+index` or even `&index[ptr]`
and arrays are *decayed* into pointers, in particular when passing them as arguments (e.g. to `printf`).

Read exactly what *decaying* an array means in your favorite C programming book. Notice that `sizeof`, when applied to an array or to a pointer, is not the same. So with `int arr[5];` on my Linux/x86-64 desktop: when passing `arr` as an argument, it is decayed to a pointer so is the same as `&arr` or `&arr[0]`; but `sizeof(arr)` is 20 but `sizeof(&arr)` is 8 (like `sizeof(ptr)` after some `int*ptr = &arr[3];`)and `sizeof(arr[0])`is 4.

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, j;
    for (j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
        printf("%p\n", &i[j]);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
0xbff22d8c
0xbff22d90
0xbff22d94
0xbff22d98
0xbff22d9c
```

Comment: That's undefined behavior unless you cast the %p args to ptr-to-void.